# How would I delete a subscribed item in Eclipse Milo 0.3.8?

Tags: opc-ua, milo

I have looked at the examples for subscribing to a NodeId and im wondering how I could stop/delete a subscription afterward.

Eclipse Milo v0.3.8 Client.

Here's what I've tried.

```
  protected boolean unsubscribe(TransactionDefinition transactionDefinition) {

// Finds the mathing TransactionDefinition from the map where all subscriptions 
// are stored, together with the clientHandle. 
// private Map<UInteger, TransactionDefinition> subscriptions = new HashMap<>();
try {
  UInteger subscriptionClientHandle = null;
  for (Map.Entry<UInteger, TransactionDefinition> entry : subscriptions.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(transactionDefinition))
      subscriptionClientHandle = entry.getKey();
  }
  if (subscriptionClientHandle == null) return false;

  try {
    client.getSubscriptionManager().deleteSubscription(subscriptionClientHandle).get();
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Subscription not found: {}", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

} catch (ClassCastException e) {
  log.error("TransactionDefinition trigger not found. {}", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Marius welcome aboard - perhaps you could could the example you wrote & that would help us direct you best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UaSubscription` has a `deleteMonitoredItems` method on it.

`UaSubscriptionManager` has a `deleteSubscription` method on it.

You could also call either of these services "manually" by invoking the "raw" service methods on the `UaClient` instance.